# Controlling AC devices using ATmega8

Tags: avr, atmega, triac, thyristor

I have an microcontroller ATmega8, TRIAC MOC3083 and thyristor M166P. I need to develop and device which will turn on/off lamp(220V).

But while I'm developing I don't want work with AC 220V now, DC 12/5V will be fine for me.

How can I connect these parts on the breadboard to be able debug my code? Please, show me a correct circuit.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it requires a complete circuit.

Comment: I just need to know HOW I can connect MC to the TRIAC and debug using DC. Is it still off-topic?

Comment: So put an LED on the output pin? What's the actual question?

Comment: The code in question shouldn't be much different considering you have a blink already working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace the MOC3083 with a visible LED (pin 1 is + pin 2 is -). Unless your drive circuit is very low voltage, the LED will indicate when the triac should be on.

[image: http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/MO/MOC3083M.pdf]